# Cohomology of sheaves of abelian groups on affine space

Tags: homology-cohomology, affine-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, affine-schemes

Is it true that $$\mathrm{H}^p_\mathrm{Zar}(\mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{K}, \mathcal{F})=0$$ for any $p>1$ and $\mathcal{F}$ (non constant) sheaf of abelian groups?

If not, is it true for some fields/sheaves but not others? Which ones?

Do you know some counterexamples?

I'd really appreciate some reference, thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, if $\mathcal{F}$ is constant. Actually this is true as long as your space is irreducible. I don't think this is true when the sheaf is a general non constant one. The point is that the constant sheaf is flabby.

Comment: For constant sheaves there is plenty of references, that's why I explicitly said *non constant* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true unless you restrict to quasicoherent sheaves.  For instance, just as a topological space, $\mathbb{A}^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, and there are coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with nontrivial $H^1$.  In fact, there are even sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}$-modules on $\mathbb{A}^n$ which have nontrivial cohomology.  For instance, let $p\in\mathbb{A}^n$ be a closed point and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the skyscraper sheaf at $p$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$ with stalk $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n, p}$.  This sheaf has a global section corresponding to $1\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n,p}$ and there is a corresponding map of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}\to\mathcal{G}$.  In fact, this map is surjective, as is easily seen by looking at stalks.  If you let $\mathcal{F}$ be its kernel, then there is an exact sequence $$H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n})\to H^0(\mathcal{G})\to H^1(\mathcal{F}).$$

But the map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}\to\mathcal{G}$ is not surjective on global sections, so it follows that $H^1(\mathcal{F})\neq 0$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Can you clarify 2 things please? The first one is that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$ (I believe that they shouldn't, since the first is contractible and the second is not). The second, more substantial, is that I do not see why the map $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{A}^n\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ is not surjective on global sections.

Comment: Ignoring the generic point, $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ both have the cofinite topology, and both have cardinality $|\mathbb{K}|+\aleph_0$, so they are homeomorphic.  The induced map on global sections from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}\to\mathcal{G}$ is just the inclusion $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{p}$, where the subscript $p$ denotes the localization at the maximal ideal corresponding to $p$.

Comment: Many thanks for the kind explanations.